# Change delimiter using vi text editor, linux

Tags: linux

I need to remove " : " delimiter from the file and replace it with "---" (three dashes) using VI text editor.
What command do I use?
Thanks

Comment: What’s wrong with `:%s/:/---/g`? Did you even *try* researching before posting?

Comment: I was wondering if there any specific commands that we use for replacing delimiters only . Thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is a common search/replace:

```
:%s/:/---/g
```

Or, remove the trailing `g` if you only want to replace the first occurence in each line.